# How to make the line graph start from zero and end at the last range JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, linegraph

[image]

I have produced a line graph like this. Even though there are no zero data for the blue line and also the red line only have the value until 100. So how do i set the blue line to start at zero and red to finish until 200 like this:

[image]

My data in textfile (outputAvgGen.txt) are:

```
11752.58,HC  
11819.65,HC  
11941.75,HC  
12398.45,HC  
12401.06,HC  
12531.09,HC  
12634.33,HC  
12748.83,HC  
12787.36,HC  
12799.44,HC 
   .  
   .  
   .   
30137.15,P3  
31919.46,P3  
32323.8,P3    
   .  
   .  
   .  
and so on until 200 data
```

This is my code:

```
public class Graph2 extends JFrame{
public Graph2(){
    setTitle("P3 Performance Analysis");
    JPanel chartPanel = createChartPanel();
    add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setSize(640, 480);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Graph2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private JPanel createChartPanel() {
    // creates a line chart object
    // returns the chart panel
    String chartTitle = "Average Fitness against No. of Generations";
    String xAxisLabel = "No. of Generations";
    String yAxisLabel = "Average Fitness";

    XYDataset dataset = createDataset();

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(chartTitle,
            xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel, dataset);

    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    yAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(true);

    return new ChartPanel(chart);
}

private XYDataset createDataset() {
    ArrayList<PlotData2> dataList = readData();

    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Hill Climber");
    XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("P3");

    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++){

        if (dataList.get(i).getAlgo().equals("HC")){
            series1.add(i, dataList.get(i).getAvg());
            System.out.println("HC i=" + i);
        }
        else if (dataList.get(i).getAlgo().equals("P3")){
            series2.add(i, dataList.get(i).getAvg());
            System.out.println("P3 i=" + i);
        }

    }

    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++){
        if (dataList.get(i).getAlgo().equals("HC")){
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
            series1.add(i, dataList.get(i).getAvg());
        }

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < dataList.size(); j++){
        if (dataList.get(j).getAlgo().equals("P3")){
            System.out.println("j = " + j);
            series2.add(j, dataList.get(j).getAvg());
        }
    }*/


    /*
    series1.add(1.0, 2.0);
    series1.add(2.0, 3.0);
    series1.add(3.0, 2.5);
    series1.add(3.5, 2.8);
    series1.add(4.2, 6.0);

    series2.add(2.0, 1.0);
    series2.add(2.5, 2.4);
    series2.add(3.2, 1.2);
    series2.add(3.9, 2.8);
    series2.add(4.6, 3.0); */

    dataset.addSeries(series1);
    dataset.addSeries(series2);

    return dataset;

}

public static ArrayList<PlotData2> readData(){
    ArrayList<PlotData2> dataList = new ArrayList<PlotData2>();

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("outputAvgGen.txt") );

        String str;
        while ( (str = in.readLine() )!= null ) {
            String[] data = str.split( "," );
            double avg = Double.parseDouble(data[0]);
            String algo = data[1];

           // int gen = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);

            dataList.add(new PlotData2(algo,avg));
        }
        in.close();
    } catch ( IOException ex ) {
        System.err.println( "Error: Can't open the file for reading." );
    }


    return dataList;
  }

}
```

Actually my original data being computed are in pairs of HC and P3 in a textfile like this:

```
15426.35,HC  
38903.93,P3
13777.49,HC
34480.21,P3
15199.38,HC
38559.36,P3
13399.15,HC
32931.49,P3  
     .  
     .  
   and so on..
```

but I sorted it to make the graph being plotted ascendingly but when sorted it doesn't plot according to the pairs.

Can someone please help with the code at least to make it start at zero and end at max range for both lines to make it look simultaneous. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] and sample data that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

The major issue with your code is that you are incrementing the x values for both series simultaneously. You need to do that separately. Furthermore, you are using hardcoded strings in your createDataset method.
Try this approach instead:

```
public static HashMap<String, List<Double>> readData() {
    HashMap<String, List<Double>> dataList = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("outputAvgGen.txt"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = str.split(",");
            String algo = data[1];
            if (dataList.get(algo) == null) {
                dataList.put(algo, new ArrayList<Double>());
            }
            dataList.get(algo).add(Double.parseDouble(data[0]));
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error: Can't open the file for reading.");
    }
    return dataList
}
private XYDataset createDataset() {
    HashMap<String, List<Double>> dataList = readData();
    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    Set<String> keys = dataList.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(key);
        List<Double> numbers = dataList.get(key);
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size() - 1; i++) {
            series.add(i, numbers.get(i), false);
        }
        series.add(numbers.size() - 1, numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1),  true);
        dataset.addSeries(series);
    }
    return dataset;
}
```